# Trying to give access to a database in sql with GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES and it dosen't work

Tags: mysql, database, heroku, import, privileges

I'm trying to deploy a project in heroku with database, i followed all the steps like install the addon clearDB and all the stuff, the problem its that i cant give the user the privileges it need, im using MySql Shell 8.0.

When i run the code it appear to be ok because it shows Query Ok, 0 rows affected, also i run FLUSH PRIVILEGES and appear the same.

Then i tryed to import the database with Data Import and always appear the error **ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'blablabla'@'%' to database 'instrumentos'.**

Its strange because i followed too the new steps, that they are create a new user and then give it to it the privileges.

```
CREATE USER 'blablabla'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON instrumentos.(*) TO 'blablabla'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit but it dosent help too much!

Comment: What is the SQL statement that causes the "Access denied" error?

Comment: I am suspicious of `instrumentos.(*)` rather than just `instrumentos.*` I guessing you don't have any table names that match that pattern.